# Не запускается Apache на windows10

Tags: windows, apache2

Установил и запускаю apache на windows10, уже полностью его настроил. Но, он не хочет запускаться и не выдаёт никаких ошибок.

Всё что происходит после запуска - ничего:

```
c:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin>tasklist | find "8000"

c:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k start

c:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin>
```

Пробовал на портах 80, 8080, но они заняты.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать что делать?

Comment: ну в лог-файлы апач же хоть что-то пишет?

Comment: Та же проблема, в логах пишет Starting the 'Apache2.4' service <br> The 'Apache2.4' service is running.